# Does memberwiseclone copy DateTime, or must it be explicitly set?

Tags: c#, .net, icloneable

I'm implementing `ICloneable` on a ton of custom objects.  Some of the objects have a type of `DateTime`, which is a struct value.  I know this value can be copied using `newDateTime = oldDateTime`, but if I use `MemberwiseClone()` on my object, does it automatically copy the `DateTime` objects?  I assume not because `DateTime` does not implement `ICloneable` itself.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`DateTime` is a value type, like `int`. So, it will be copied by the MemberwiseClone().

Answer (score 3):

Since `DateTime` is value type, it will be copied.

[Object.MemberwiseClone Method - MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.memberwiseclone.aspx)

> The MemberwiseClone method creates a shallow copy by creating a new
>   object, and then copying the nonstatic fields of the current object to
>   the new object. **If a field is a value type, a bit-by-bit copy of the
>   field is performed.** If a field is a reference type, the reference is
>   copied but the referred object is not; therefore, the original object
>   and its clone refer to the same object.